# Converting from A to B using mapped key

Tags: vimrc, vimscript, key-bindings, global-command

I've posted a number of times to try and get closer to what I'm trying to do. My problem is I have got the commands I need to make the conversion happen, however I cannot successfully map it to a key.

This is the type of sequences I have to convert (123456789 representing any number combination):

```
0010|C|||N12345678|W1234567891234
0010|H|S12345678|E123456789||
0020|L|N12345678|W123456789|N12345678|W12345678912341234
0030|G|N12345678|W123456789||
0020|R|N12345678|W123456789|N12345678|W12345678912341234
```

This is my desired outcome:

```
0010|C|||N12345678|W123456789|123.4
0010|H|S12345678|E123456789||
0020|L|N12345678|W123456789|N12345678|W123456789|123.4|123.4
0030|G|N12345678|W123456789||
0020|R|N12345678|W123456789|N12345678|W123456789|123.4|123.4
```

A member on reddit came up with two global commands which does exactly what I need it to:

```
:global/|C|/execute "normal $3hi|\<Esc>$i."

:g/|L|\||R|/execute "normal $7hi|\<Esc>4li.\<Esc>2li|\<Esc>$i."
```

anyone able to map it to a single key?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Trying to cram that in a single line could get a bit ugly without any particular advantage. Simplest approach is going to be to put the commands in a function in your vimrc like so:

```
function! ConvertNumCols()
  global/|C|/execute "normal $3hi|\<Esc>$i."
  g/|L|\||R|/execute "normal $7hi|\<Esc>4li.\<Esc>2li|\<Esc>$i."
endfunction
```

Along with a mapping that calls it

```
nnoremap X :call ConvertNumCols()<CR>
```

Replace `X` with whatever key or keys that you want.